# Anime about a demon princess who is banished to the human world and falls in love with a knight sent to protect her

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm looking for an anime about a demon princess who gets banished to the human world, but is not sent alone. There is a knight sent to protect her and they fall in love. The princess has pink hair and the knight's hair is blue.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, was this a series or a movie?

Comment: Pink hair for the princess is fairly standard, same with blue hair for the night, neither of those help much. Was this set in a fantasy world, modern (Japan) or future? The first that comes to mind is Testament of Sister New Devil, but she had red hair and the knight wasn't sent to protect her but ends up protecting her anyway.